# Comparing edittext input with a string (android)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to compare user input in my edittext with the string provided in the code. If they are matching, I want to increment the value of the integer score. I read many similar questions and adjusted my code but still, it seems not to work as the value of the integer does not change.
I put it in the method that is called while clicking a button, it also allows to go to another question(change layout)

```
int score=0;
public void nextPage3(View v) {
    findViewById(R.id.q2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String a = input.getText().toString();
            String p = "poet";
            if (p.equalsIgnoreCase(a))
                score++;
       }});

    setContentView(R.layout.question3);

}
```

Comment: Is your `nextPage3` method declared inside your xml `Button` as `onClick` event? If it is, why are you calling inside the body od method `setOnClickListener`? And what is `setContentView` doing in your `onClick` event?

Comment: Did you debug your code? Could it be that the score is increased, but you do not refresh the label (or whatever) that shwos the score?

Comment: @Yupi yes. Thank you, I am a beginner I didn't realize it's totally unnecessary here. I removed it and it's working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write Like This

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    onCreate
     {
          setContentView(R.layout.question3);
     }
public void nextPage3(View v) {
    findViewById(R.id.q2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String a = input.getText().toString();
            String p = "poet";
            if (p.equalsIgnoreCase(a))
                score++;
       }});
}
}
```

Do Not Forget To add On Click Event In Xml File.
If You Do Not Declare Then Get Button Using FindViewById And btnName.setOnClickListenr() Method